# JavaFX label font doesn't change based on CSS file

Tags: css, javafx

I have a FXML file that looks like this:

```
...
<BorderPane id="header">
    <right>
        <Label styleClass="title" text="A Label" />
    </right>
</BorderPane>
...
```

And a CSS file:

```
#header .title { -fx-text-file: #FFFFFF; -fx-font-size: 18px; }
```

The `-fx-text-file` property applies, making the label white, but the `-fx-font-size: 18px` doesn't change the font size. Even stranger, when I specify the `-fx-font-size` in a style (adding `style="-fx-font-size: 18px;"` to my Label element in FXML), it does change the font size!

Any idea why it's not working from the CSS file?

Comment: `-fx-text-file`???

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me, It may be due to the font, although I doubt it. try with another font or by changing the value into a larger one and  **Correct the css statement** :

```
       -fx-text-fill:#FFFFFF
```

not :

```
      -fx-text-file
```